# enviar formData con fetch

Tags: fetch, formdata

Tengo un código similar a este y funciona bien el problema es cuando uno de los parámetros a enviar posee el operador =, automáticamente no se envía ese carácter en la petición, supongo que es que la sintaxis de esta request usa el = para  asignar clave = valor, mi duda es existe alguna forma de que el valor contenga = y no lo elimine.

```
fetch("api/xxx", {

    body: "email=test@example.com&password=pw",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    method: "post",
}
```

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0):

Para enviar FormData no te hace falta convertirlo a cadena de texto con sus pares clave/valor. Lo puedes usar directamente, tal como reza su [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#body) como uno de los tipos aceptados.

Para seguir con tu ejemplo vamos a crear un nuevo objeto FormData con esto:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('email', 'test@example.com');
formData.append('password', "pw");

fetch("api/xxx", {

    body: formData,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    method: "post",
}
```

pero es aplicable a los datos recuperados de un formulario también.

Lo que tu pretendes no parece posible, no de ese modo, no lo he sabido encontrar en dicha documentación.